# Json Gson not working (Exception object / String)

Tags: java, json, gson

i have a problem of transfer JSON to java type, I want to transfer this JSON:

```
{ "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse", "columns": [  "Pre",  "Post" ], "rows": [  [   "Si2",   "Si2"  ],  [   "CeSP-A",   "CeSP-A"  ],  [   "Si2",   "Si1"  ],  [   "Si1",   "Si2"  ],  [   "Si2",   "Si1"  ],  [   "Si1",   "Si2"  ] ]}
```

to a java list which each one of the list has two private string Pre and Post

Here is my code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Edges> list = gson.fromJson(jsonU,
                new TypeToken<List<Edges>>() {
                }.getType());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Edges p = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(p.getPre() + ", " + p.getPost());
            System.out.println();
        }
```

and 
jsonU is the String of JSON file

```
{ "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse", "columns": [  "Pre",  "Post" ], "rows": [  [   "Si2",   "Si2"  ],  [   "CeSP-A",   "CeSP-A"  ],  [   "Si2",   "Si1"  ],  [   "Si1",   "Si2"  ],  [   "Si2",   "Si1"  ],  [   "Si1",   "Si2"  ] ]}
```

However, i got the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

can you please help me resolve this problem? Thank you very much

Comment: public class Edges {
  private String pre;
  private String post;

  public String getPre() {
   return pre;
  }

  public void setPre(String pre) {
   this.pre = pre;
  }

  public String getPost() {
   return post;
  }

  public void setPost(String post) {
   this.post = post;
  }

 }

Answer (score 0):

You are telling GSON to deserialize a `List<Edges>` yet the JSON you are passing starts with an object, with the `{` and `}` tokens.

GSON, based on the type parameters you've passed to it, is expecting something like:

```
[
    { "kind": .... },
    { "kind: .... },
    ...
]
```

In other words, how can GSON construct a List of something when you are passing it JSON corresponding to a single object?